# Calling a class within Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to call a class within jquery.

```
<nav class="small-nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li> </ul>
</nav> <!-- End of small-nav -->

<script>$('.handle').on('click', function() 
{$('nav .small-nav ul').toggleClass('open'); 
});
</script>
```

However this doesn't work. I've tried replacing as

```
$('small-nav ul') or $('.small-nav ul') or $("nav '.small-nav' ul")
or $('nav.small-nav ul')
```

and it doesn't seem to work.

I know the code is fine because when I remove the class from the nav and when I call just the nav ul as shown below, it works.

```
<nav>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</nav>

<script>$('.handle').on('click', function() 
{$('nav ul').toggleClass('open'); 
});
</script>
```

So can someone please tell me how I can call the specific class? Or is it not working because I am trying to call a class within another class (open) ? How do I fix it so that I can call that particular nav class and not all nav in my website.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: there is no `ul` in your markup.. so use `<nav class="small-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>` then `$('nav.small-nav ul')`

Comment: ul or li you want to use?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the ul when posting, I'll edit it now.

Comment: Try wrapping your code in `document.ready`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `find();` like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.handle').on('click', function(){
    $('nav.small-nav').find('ul').toggleClass('open'); 
    });

})

</script>
```

[Jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution didnt worked because you have wrong selector for targetting `nav` with class `small-nav`. also ensure that events are attached when dom isready.You need to use:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.handle').on('click', function(){    
$('nav.small-nav ul').toggleClass('open'); 
});
});
```

Comment: I used the google web developers jquery code. I pasted the link to my head section.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('nav > .small-nav ul').toggleClass('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery does not work because you are looking for the `.small-nav` element inside the `nav` (`nav .small-nav`), not a `.nav` element which has that class (`nav.small-nav`). Try this:

```
<nav class="small-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.handle').on('click', function() {
        $('nav.small-nav ul').toggleClass('open'); 
    });
</script>
```

This code is obviously assuming that you have an element with the class `handle` in your code - as it is not shown in your OP example.

Comment: Yea I already have the ul. I forgot to type it out here. Edited my original post. Sorry.

Comment: Yea I do have the handle class. Just that i forgot to add to here again, lol. But this new one still doesn't work. I've tried this.

Comment: @gosi123 have you checked the console for errors? Is jquery.js included in your page?

Comment: I used the jquery from google developers, so basically I just pasted the link to my head section. I think the whole code is fine, because if I remove all classes in nav , it works. I just want to call a specific nav instead of all nav.